# interate through two list to get elements in a tuple in python

Tags: python, loops, tuples

I need to iterate through two lists of sentences (premises and hypothesis) to get tuples of
premises and hypotheses.

What I have done so far is below:

```
def examples (premises, hypotheses, labels):
    labels = list(labels)

    ls=[]


   for pr, hy in zip(premises, hypotheses):
      prs=tuple(pr, hy)
      ls=ls.append(prs)
```

I need pairs of premises and hypotheses in a tuple appended to a list. Does my code make sense?

Comment: What is the label list for?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Does my code make sense?” is not a Stack Overflow issue.
What problem do you have when you run the code?  The Python interpreter is your ultimate authority for functionality.  You seem to be asking for a premature (off-topic) code review (wrong site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few correctable problems: 1. You didn't return ls; 2. The .append method mutates ls so you shouldn't say ls = ls.append(); 3. when you iterate with two variables through the zip object, you get a tuple automatically, so you don't want to cast it as a tuple. Finally, I am not sure what you want to do with labels. The correct version of your code is:

```
def examples (premises, hypotheses, labels):
    labels = list(labels)
    ls=[]
    for pr, hy in zip(premises, hypotheses):
      prs = pr, hy
      ls.append(prs)
    return ls
```

Comment: One can simply use `ls.append((pr, hy))`

Comment: @ack Absolutely.  There are many ways to make this code more concise.  It can be a one-line list comprehension.  I am trying to stick with Natalia's original code to show her where it went wrong.

Comment: @ack or just not even unpack the tuple from `zip` and just do `for pair in zip(...)` and `ls.append(pair)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this :

```
def examples (premises, hypotheses, labels):
    labels = list(labels)

    ls=[]


    for i in range(len(premises)):
        tupl = (premises[i], hypotheses[i])
        ls.append(tupl)
```

Also do not use `ls=ls.append(Something)` the .append does not return anything, it just modifies the list. Use it like this `ls.append(Something)`

Comment: `for variable in range(len( ...` is almost always at least un-pythonic (if not bad) when you use _variable_ just for indexing. See Ned Batchelder's famous [Loop Like A Native](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html).

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way would be to use `list comprehension`:

```
def f(premises, hypotheses):
    return [(p, h) for p, h in zip(premises, hypotheses)]

p = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
h = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

print("This is output of my function:", f(p, h))
```

Output:

```
This is output of my function: [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4')]
```

Comment: You could even reduce it down to `return list(zip(premises, hypotheses))`